# Shortcut to open Firefox instead of Internet Explorer

Tags: firefox, startup, shortcut

We're presenting a site that we've done for a client and put this all on a flash drive. I have installed Firefox portable because I'd like for the site to open in Firefox.

I've then created a shortcut which points to the index.html page on the flash drive but I would like for the shortcut to open the site in Firefox on that flash drive instead of IE, which will most likely be the client's default browser.

Can someone tell me how the Start In entry works in order to open the shortcut in another app please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't notice 'Firefox portable'.
Put a batch file on your flash drive, and use:

```
FirefoxPortable\App\firefox.exe files\customers\index.html
```

Assuming that Firefox is installed in FirefoxPortable\App and the page to be displayed in files\customers\index.html